# Schengen expiry

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-expiration

I have a valid multi trip Schengen VISA which is getting expired the very next day I’d be  exiting from schengen area (Czech Republic - Prague).

I’d be entering through France (from India) exactly 10 days before the expiry date and after visiting France, Croatia and Czech Republic, will leave Schengen area on the 9th day (Prague - a day before VISA expires)

Will there be any issues doing so?

Comment: Why would there be any issues?

Answer (score 5):

If your flight is somehow cancelled and you are unable to leave before your visa expires there could be an issue, but you have left a whole day as a buffer. If there are delays/cancellations, you likely will still be able to get a flight out the same or next day. As long as you do not overstay, you're fine